# .htaccess 301 Redirect Multiple URLs to one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an ecommerce site which currently has product URLs like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt/Large

http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt/Medium

http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt/Small
```

On the new site the different sizes all point to one URL, so I need to .htaccess direct these three URLs to the one page. Instead of doing each one separately, I would like to do it as a regular expression, so that any URL with the first part followed by any size will redirect to the new URL.

```
E.g: 301 redirect /nike-tshirt/[reg exp.] http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt.html
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Here's the current Magento .htaccess:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will redirect anything starting with /nike-tshirt/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nike-tshirt/ http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt.html [R=301]
```

This will redirect more specifically, any of the 3 listed sizes.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nike-tshirt/(Large|Medium|Small) http://www.mydomain.com/nike-tshirt.html [R=301]
```

Edit: removed extra slash.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, for some reason it hasn't worked yet... This is what I have:

    RewriteRule ^nike/nike-sports-bra/ http://www.mydomain.com/nike-sports-bra.html [R=301]

Comment: Make sure that you have `RewriteEngine On` and that your server supports mod_rewrite. Also if using a .htaccess file make sure that it is in the root directory of the website. Do you have any other rewrite rules that could interfere? Do you define the rewrite base? If you can upload the complete file it might be helpful.

Comment: I've pasted the entire htaccess into my question. It's the default Magento htaccess.

Comment: It's just started working! I don't know why it wasn't before, but it is now - so thanks for your help!

Comment: I have same scenerio but I have loads of URLs to redirect and dot have similarity like above URL have nike-tshir